# Scraping data with vba from Yahoo finance

Tags: excel, web-scraping, yahoo-finance, vba

I need to read the closing price of a stock from the Yahoo Finance page. I had this answered before using Google Finance page, but the page is no longer available and I believe Google has completely changed its Finance page. I believe I can apply the same on Yahoo Finance with little modification.

Let s say Yahoo Finance has the following code for the stock symobol AAPL (Apple):

```
    ![YAHOO WEBPAGE CODE FOR AAPL][1]
```

I need to only extract the value 172.77.

This was working perfectly with Google Finance page. In my code below.

The line:

```
    "https://finance.google.com/finance?q="
```

is replaced by:

```
    "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"
```

The code loops in a range of cells and reads the stock symbols. We need to get the same results but from the Yahoo page instead.

```
    Sub ImportCurrentPriceNEW()
    Dim appIE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim item_data As Object    

    For k = 6 To 26 Step 1
     s = 1
     H = 1
     L = 1
     StopLoop = 0
     q = Format(k, "0")
     If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("$E$" & q).Value) = True Then  

     With appIE
    .Visible = False
    .navigate "https://finance.google.com/finance?q=" & Sheets("Up Trend 
     Stocks").Range("$A$" & q).Value
    Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set html = .document
    End With

   Set item_data = html.querySelector(".pr span")
   Range("$B$" & q).Value = item_data.innerText               
   End If    
Next    
appIE.Quit
Range("D1").Select

End Sub
```

Please let me know how I can modify code above to read data from Yahoo Finance page.

Comment: Please do not use all-caps in your question title - it is considered yelling at your readers.

Comment: Please copy the data snippet as text instead of a screenshot to enable people her to reproduce your problem without having to re-type the data.

Comment: @Filburt I am afraid I didn't understand what you  mean exactly. Could you please clarify?
Also, question title is not in all-caps. 
Thanks

Comment: It's not in all-caps any more because I edited it.

Comment: My bad.....Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you have an aversion to google, but I think you should consider using this small utility.

http://investexcel.net/multiple-stock-quote-downloader-for-excel/

[image]

That should do everything you want and a while lot more!!

Otherwise, in Excel, under the Data tab, click Existing Connections and then click MSN Money Central Investor Stock Quotes.  See the image below.  Enter your tickers/symbols, and click Open.

[image]

If the app is not installed already, click the link below, and follow the steps to get everything setup and working on your machine.

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104379220?tab=Overview

[image]

Comment: Hello - I believe your model no longer works for Google Finance. Please check.

Comment: Ah, you are right.  OK, well, I haven't used that process in a while.  Now I'm using R and quantmod for all my historical time series data points.  https://www.quantmod.com/

Comment: Regardless, your model works to get historical prices. How about getting real time prices. Do you have this?

Comment: I do not have those connections in my Excel version. How do you get it?

Comment: I just updated my original post...again.  I took the first screen shot from my office machine; the second one came from my laptop at home.  I just did this now, for the first time ever.  Follow the steps in the last link.  It's very intuitive.  You should be up and running in just a few minutes.  Please up-vote the my post if this information is helpful and useful for you!!  Good luck!!

Comment: Could you please give me the VBA code for importing the historical data. I just want the simple code for only one symbol, for example "AAPL". Can you write this please?
Thanks

Comment: Dude, are you reading anything that I posted here?  I gave you several solutions and you keep changing your question.  Try this:  www.google.com
Hopefully that will help you.

Comment: My friend I am not changing my question. My initial question was related to current prices which I had it figured out. I know you provided an answer for it, but I had another solution that works better with the model I build. 
I do need however the historical sale, but I just need the code that an do it and I can modify it to fit my model. The tool you are providing is definitely excellent, but I already have a tool and need to implement some changes to it. I definitely read all your posts and I do appreciate it.

Comment: It seems like Yahoo and Google have done away with their APIs for Excel, so now a days these time series data sets seem to be pretty limited.  I use Python and R for these kinds of things now, so I didn't realize this until just now.  Take a look at the link below.  Hopefully that will work.  Post your feedback for the others who come here looking for the same info.  https://blog.quandl.com/api-for-stock-data

Comment: I can't use these kinds of things in my office.  Everything is blocked when I am behind the firewall.  Good luck!!

Answer (score 3):

Try the below way. It should fetch you the value of `AAPL` from `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/`. To reach the value using `class` name or `tag` name is in reality troublesome. However, I used static `id` here.

```
Sub Fetch_Quote()
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, elem As Object, URL$
    URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL"

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document

        Set elem = HTML.getElementById("quote-market-notice").PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling
        MsgBox elem.innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

Then try this. Now, you should get the result with the blink of an eye:

```
Sub Fetch_Quote()
    Dim HTML As New HTMLDocument, elem As Object, URL$
    URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        Set elem = HTML.getElementById("quote-market-notice").PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling
        MsgBox elem.innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft XML, V6.0
```

Comment: Hello - I have modified the code a little to loop around a range of cells. It s working perfectly as intended. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello - I have noticed my computer gets extremely slow everytime I run this. The temporary internet folder size increases, and my computer is juts slow. I have to clean it up to get back to normal. Any idea why?

Comment: See the updated code. It will fetch you the result in no time.

Comment: This is just perfect! Can you please tell me in simple words why the previous code was so slow and causing the computer to slow after running?