# VBA Application-Defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, yahoo-finance

I am new to VBA and would like to run the following code block in order retrieve the price of a stock. It appears its somewhat working because when I run the macro I get the prompt to enter the ticker symbol, however when I do I get an error message that says Application-Defined or object defined error. I'm not sure if perhaps the application webservice has been deprecated or something totally different. I'm using a macbook pro with excel version 16.42 - I am aware the activeX features don't work with this os but i'm assuming because the prompt gets initiated it should work anyways. any help would be immensely appreciated.

here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Declaring_Variables()

Dim TickerName As String

TickerName = InputBox("Ticker Symbol")

Dim CurrentPrice As String

CurrentPrice = Application.WebService("finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & TickerName & 
"&f=l1")

MsgBox "Text Format: " & CurrentPrice & Chr(10) & _
    "Number Format: " & Application.NumberValue(CurrentPrice)

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think that URL is valid. Using `=WEBSERVICE("finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=l1")` as a formula, I get the response: `"<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Document Has Moved</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR=""white"" FGCOLOR=""black"">
<H1>Document Has Moved</H1>
<HR>

<FONT FACE=""Helvetica,Arial""><B>
Description: The document you requested has moved to a new location.  The new location is ""http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=l1"".
</B></FONT>
<HR>
</BODY>
"
`

Comment: see second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510545/scraping-data-with-vba-from-yahoo-finance  make sure to add references: microsoft html object library and microsoft xml,6.0